# Prestashop php.ini wrong parameters

Tags: server, apache2, php

I installed LAMP on Contabo's VPS. I made changes to the php.ini file as required:

```
marcin@vmi11:~$ php -i |grep "php.ini"
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/8.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
```

PHP.INI:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
; https://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 256M
```

I used this [file](https://github.com/PrestaShop/php-ps-info/blob/master/phppsinfo.php).Prestashop doesn't see it:
[php_presta_shop_info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S70F.png)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You are editing the wrong `php.ini` file.

The `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini` file is loaded when running PHP on the command line.

If you want to update PHP configurations for your webserver, you need to edit `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini`. It may also be under an `apache2` folder `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini`.